# How do I extract unique characters from a string?

Tags: c#

I have a string, "aabbcccddeefddg", and I want to extract the unique characters from it. The result set should be "abcdefg".

**Note**: I don't want to use the String.Distinct function in C#.

Comment: "Note: I don't want to use string.distinct function in c#."  Why not?  Is this homework?

Comment: i have constraint that should not use regular expr or string existing functions

Comment: Are you trying to extract characters by passing a reference number?  For example, the letter at the 2nd position in the string "abcdef" is 'b'.  Or do you want it to search the string for letters and return whether or  not the letter exists? Be more specific please.

Comment: So where is the unique characters? What you are looking for is a way to remove multiple duplicate characters typed right after each other.

Comment: BTW, there is no `String.Distinct` method. `Distinct` is an extension method that extends `IEnumerable<T>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
static string extract(string original)
        {
            List<char> characters = new List<char>();
            string unique = string.Empty;

            foreach (char letter in original.ToCharArray())
            {
                if (!characters.Contains(letter))
                {
                    characters.Add(letter);
                }
            }

            foreach (char letter in characters)
            {
                unique += letter;
            }

            return unique;
}
```

Comment: what is the type for characters variable

Comment: characters is a list of char.  
List<char> characters = new List<char>();

Answer (score 5):

Not sure why you don't want to use `Distinct`, but here's a solution using a `HashSet<char>`:

```
HashSet<char> chars = new HashSet<char>();
string s = "aabbcccddeefddg";
foreach(char c in s)
{
    chars.Add(c);
}

foreach(char c in chars)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c);
}
```

Comment: Note that this will not return the characters in the order they appeared. Not sure if this is a requirement, but the OP's example seems to suggest that it might be.

Comment: @hammar, you're right. If that's an issue, use the `SortedSet<T>` class instead

Comment: That will return them in ASCII order, though.

Comment: @ShaliniPavan, oh really? Did you try?

Comment: @Thomas - You can try: `if (chars.Contains(c)) continue; chars.Add(c); result += c;`

Comment: Hey Thomas i am sorry dont mind the above comment i tried looping string it's been working never tried before .

Comment: This solution will also works, except it does not return in order

Answer (score 1):

Check out the pseudo code below

```
initialize array index[256] to 0

for (i=0; i<length_of_string; i++)
{
  index[string[i]]++;
}

for (i=0; i<256; i++)
{
  if (index[i] > 0)
    print ascii of **i** 
}
```

**UPDATE**

The below loop will print the characters in the order in which it appeared in the original string.

```
for (i=0; i<256; i++)
{
  if (index[i] > 0)
  {
    index[i] = 0
    print ascii of **i**
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or split the string into an array of chars. Then loop through it. Take the remainder (everything after the current letter) of the string (with substring) and use String.Replace on it to remove other references of the same letter. Then concatenate the result back with the first part. Do this for every letter.

Problem also solved.

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = "AAABBBBBCCCCFFFFGGGGGDDDDJJJJJJ";

var newstr = String.Join("", s.Distinct());
```